# Running Javascript function when new items are added to a SharePoint Calendar

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, dom-events

I need to color events in calendar list view.

I use `_spbodyonloadfunctionnames.push(myFunction)`, but my function executes when page load.

If I add new event this function doesn't execute.

How could I color new event?

Comment: @John - it is terrible, but isn't that the point of the Edit?

Comment: @Ryan: it's also the point of my comment - to give the OP the opportunity to rethink his terrible title. That's especially important in this case, where the question was unclear, so I could not see what the title should have been. Hopefully, the OP knew, and could tell us if he took a moment to think about the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be some magic array/function to handle when partial requests are executed in the list views, but for now what I can suggest is to monkey patch the refreshItems method for the calendar, so you call your function on the load event and the patched event.

```
(function(){
    var oldRefreshItems = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarContainer.prototype.refreshItems;
    SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarContainer.prototype.refreshItems = function(){
        alert("I happen on every partial refresh"); // your function
        return oldRefreshItems.call(this, null);
    };
})();
```